# Choosing minimum among minima using Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, parallel-processing, parallel-extensions

I am new to C#, `Parallel.ForEach`, and .NET in general.  I want to parallelize a search that involves thousands of locations.  For each location, I compute great circle distance.  That is a calculation I want to spread to different cores.  My question is how do I do this if I only have **one** thread-local variable, as in this [MSDN TPL example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997393.aspx)?  For the result, I looked at `Interlocked`, and saw its options `Add`, `CompareExchange`, `Decrement`, `Exchange`, `Increment` and `Read`, but I'm not just adding, incrementing, decrementing, or testing for equality.  I want to return the object, over several threads running in parallel, that has the shortest **overall** distance.  My gut says this should be easy, that I should be able to create some little object that wraps a `Location` and a distance, but how do I capture the best answer from each thread and *then* choose the shortest distance among them?  Here is the non-parallel version:

```
Location findClosestLocation(Location myLocation, List<Location> allLocations)
{
  double closest = double.MaxValue;
  Location closestLoc = null;
  foreach (Location aLoc in allLocations)
  {
    if (aLoc != myLocation)
    {
      double d = greatCircle(myLocation, aLoc);
      if (d < closest)
      {
        closest = d;
        closestLoc = aLoc;
      }
    }
  }
  return closestLoc;
}
```

I did see a [DDJ Blog Post](http://www.drdobbs.com/blog/archives/2010/03/exploiting_mult.html) that seemed to offer good advice, but I wondered if it was the best advice.  I see the author looping over arrays, and wonder if there isn't a more functional way of doing this.  In the functional world I would use `map`, `lambda` and `min`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest option here would be to switch to PLINQ:

```
Location findClosestLocation(Location myLocation, List<Location> allLocations)
{
     return allLocations
               .AsParallel()
               .Min(location => greatCircle(myLocation, location));
}
```

---

That being said, this is basically just [aggregation with parallel constructs](http://reedcopsey.com/2010/01/22/parallelism-in-net-part-4-imperative-data-parallelism-aggregation/).  You have a couple of options if you want to stick to the Parallel class.  One option would be to synchronize this yourself within the block, using locking.  I wouldn't recommend this, as it will hurt your overall performance.

The better option is to use the [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990270.aspx) methods which provide for local state.  They would allow you to rewrite this as:

```
Location findClosestLocation(Location myLocation, List<Location> allLocations)
{
  double closest = double.MaxValue;
  Location closestLoc = null;
  object sync = new object();

  Parallel.ForEach<Location, Tuple<double,Location>(
      allLocations,
      () => new Tuple(double.MaxValue, null),
      (location, loopState, localState) =>
      {
          double d = greatCircle(myLocation, aLoc);
          if (d < localState.Item1)
              return new Tuple(d, aLoc);
          else
              return localState;
      },
      localState =>
      {
          lock(sync)
          {
              if (localState.Item1 < closest)
              {
                  closest = localState.Item1;
                  closestLoc = localState.Item2;
              }
          }
      }
  );
  return closestLoc;
}
```

I cover using [local state for aggregations in detail on my blog](http://reedcopsey.com/2010/01/22/parallelism-in-net-part-4-imperative-data-parallelism-aggregation/).  This basically changes the operation to one lock operation per thread instead of one lock per processing element, so you get much higher throughput than a naive locking solution.

Comment: Wow, that's about as short and sweet as it gets.  It makes my functional heart sing.  Thanks!

Comment: @gknauth: Yeah - I added the (correct/performant) Parallel.ForEach option too.  I recommend learning **how** the other option works, and trying to understand it.  It's valuable, though, for most of these operations, I just use PLINQ since it's awesome.

Comment: Thanks for clueing me into your blog too, looks great.  Write a book, I'll buy it!  Or if that's too much work, I'll buy you dinner.

Comment: @gknauth: Heh, thanks - I've considered it, but there are some good ones coming out shortly.  The Patterns and Practices TPL book will be out electronically in August (print in Oct.).  I helped review it - it's a good one.  In the meantime, I've got a ton of stuff on this topic on my blog (with more on the way ;) )